# When can we take $A$ somehow out of $\langle x,Ay\rangle$?

Tags: inner-products

Let $A$ be a linear mapping on an inner product space $V$ and $x,y \in V$.
What are some cases (as general as possible) can we take $A$ somehow out of $\langle x,Ay\rangle$? (I know when $A = c I$, we can).

Source of question: I almost made a mistake by $\langle x,Ay\rangle = A \langle x,y\rangle$.
Thanks.

Comment: We want $<x,Ay>=f(<x,y>)$ for some function $f$. The condition is equivalent to: Whenever $<x_1,y_1>=<x_2,y_2>$ we must have $<x_1,Ay_1>=<x_2,Ay_2>$. From this prove that $A$ must be diagonalizable with unique eigenvalue, because it cant change direction of vectors.